# VueJs + TypeScript | Module build failed: Error: Could not find file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, typescript, webpack, vuejs2

I am running into issue using TypeScript, Webpack with VueJS

Every time when I type in `<script lang="ts"></script>` I am running into error: 
'Module build failed: Error: Could not find file'.

I am using template: 'dotnet new –install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*' 'dotnet new vue'

- ASP.NET MVC Core 2.0
- Vue.js 2
- TypeScript

Any suggestions how to fix this error?

Comment: I really hate `<script lang="ts"></script>` it just feels at cross purposes with TypeScript

Comment: I am quite new to VueJS and Typescript and almost everywhere developers are using 'lang.ts' but I cannot make it work.

Comment: what is your entry file?

Comment: entry: { 'main': './ClientApp/boot.ts' },